# What is call s:X(...) which is used often in color schemes in vim

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

Can someone please explain or point me to the meaning and use of the function s:X(...) which is called for different syntax groups in color schemes.

```
call s:X("CursorLine","","1c1c1c","","",s:termBlack)
```

Comment: Can you link to an example color scheme?

Comment: https://github.com/geoffharcourt/one-dark.vim/blob/master/onedark.vim

Comment: function definition: https://github.com/geoffharcourt/one-dark.vim/blob/master/onedark.vim#L214

Comment: I am so stupid!!!! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Do you also have go to definition or declaration for vim files?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

The s: is a definition of a script local function, as explained in `:help local-function`. For your case the function is defined [here](https://github.com/geoffharcourt/one-dark.vim/blob/master/onedark.vim#L214).

### Using ctags

[Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) works for vimL and can be easily be accessed from Vim (`:help 29.1`). . As you are using git repositories, you [could perform the setup describe here](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) in order to automagically create the tags when you download or update the repo.